# How to reset an interface input argument to nil and caller can do nil check?

Tags: go, interface

I have a function `unmarshal` takes an `e` interface as one of the input args and will unmarshal data to the interface and then the caller can access the result.

When `count` is 0, would like to reset `e` to `nil`, so caller can also test if it's nil. Don't wanna return an error when count = 0

```golang
func unmarshall(data []byte, count int, e interface{}) error {

    if count == 0 {
        e = (*student)(nil)
        return nil
    }

    return json.Unmarshal(data, e)
}

type student struct {
    Name string
}
```

Full Example:
https://play.golang.org/p/ijSIgvQE1Ik

The code can be compiled and run with no issue, but I just didn't get what I want. And I know there are other ways to get around it. It would be great if someone can explain what is happening behind the scene.

Comment: Either https://play.golang.org/p/nMCxjCPpmF7 or use multiple return values https://play.golang.org/p/7STlPTZc3J9

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am curious why my code doesn't work as expected as well. Do you have any insight?

Comment: Because your function gets a copy of the interface passed into it.

Comment: @Volker but if I unmarshal data to `e`, then `e` is modified and it is available outside of the func.

Comment: @lolol: Only if `e` is a pointer, in which case you're not modifying `e` at all - you're modifying the thing that `e` points to.

Comment: @lolol a function cannot modify the *immediate* value passed to it by the caller, at least one level of indirection is required. To illustrate, given a function `F` and a type `T`, the function `F(T)` cannot modify the caller's `T`, the function `F(*T)` can modify the caller's `T` but cannot modify the caller's `*T`, the function `F(**T)` can modify the caller's `T` and `*T` but cannot modify the caller's `**T`, and so on.